# Vertically align SVG text stripes

Tags: svg, alignment, vertical-alignment, text-alignment

What SVG technique can I use to perfectly vertically align text stripes? This SVG makes horizontal stripes with `rect` and attempts to layer `text` on each stripe with perfect vertical alignment but it looks slightly off. I'm seeking a cross-browser technique that works with different fonts.

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 300 300" width="100%" style="font: 1em/1 sans-serif">
  <title>flavors</title>
  <rect width="300" height="100" x="0" y="0" fill="lime" />
  <rect width="300" height="100" x="0" y="100" fill="yellow" />
  <rect width="300" height="100" x="0" y="200" fill="plum" />
  <text alignment-baseline="middle" font-size="50" x="10" y="50" fill="black">APPLE</text>
  <text alignment-baseline="middle" font-size="50" x="10" y="150" fill="black">BANANA</text>
  <text alignment-baseline="middle" font-size="50" x="10" y="250" fill="black">CHERRY</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: Please take a look at the browser compatibility for [alignement-baseline](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/alignment-baseline#Browser_Compatibility)
Instead of using `alignment-baseline` you can use `dy` to change the position of the text to what you need: `<text font-size="50" x="10" y="50" dy=".25em" >APPLE</text>`

Comment: Thanks yes `y` and `dy` can adjust it but the amount seems to differ depending on the font. I can tell `alignement-baseline` is supported because changing the value changes the alignment. MDN saying `?` means unreported. They link its definition dating back to [SVG 1.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/text.html#AlignmentBaselineProperty)

Comment: Thanks for adding the code snippet runner too :)

Comment: In fact `dy` should be about 1/4 of the font size

Comment: Using [`ex`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#ex) like about `dy=".2ex"` seems best so far

Answer (score 1):

To get reliable results, you will need to specify the exact font to use.  At the moment you are just relying on the default font.  Whatever that may be.  The default font will depend on the browser, the browser settings and/or the operating system.

Also remember that not every font will include the data that `alignment-baseline` uses.  That's why it suggested that you don't rely on `alignment-baseline` unless you (a) know the exact font you are using supports it, and (b) every browser, that might be used, supports `alignment-baseline` and (c) everywhere, the SVG is displayed, has that font available.

The alternative `dy` technique only requires that you know that the font will be available.

For example if you know that Arial will always be available, you can use a `dy` of `0.35em` which is known to be around the right value for Arial.  And since it uses `em` units, it will work for any font size.

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 300 300" width="100%" style="font-family: Arial">
  <title>flavors</title>
  <rect width="300" height="100" x="0" y="0" fill="lime" />
  <rect width="300" height="100" x="0" y="100" fill="yellow" />
  <rect width="300" height="100" x="0" y="200" fill="plum" />
  <text font-size="50" x="10" y="50" fill="black" dy="0.35em">APPLE</text>
  <text font-size="50" x="10" y="150" fill="black" dy="0.35em">BANANA</text>
  <text font-size="50" x="10" y="250" fill="black" dy="0.35em">CHERRY</text>
</svg>
```